# How to know as soon as the sql job agent is executed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

Am running a sql server job from my front end console application, and now i need a return response from the database as soon as the job is executed. 
I know that If i send another command on the same running job i can have the return status as job in progress, but i need to know how do i get the response from the database as soon as the job is executed. I will use that status in my application to show, Job executed successfully.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get information about SQL jobs in `msdb` tables `sysjobs` and `sysjobhistory`.

```
SELECT job.name
    , CASE jobHistory.run_status
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Success'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Cancelled'
END AS Run_Status
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs job
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jobHistory ON job.job_id = jobHistory.job_id
WHERE job.name = 'your job name'
GROUP BY job.name, jobHistory.run_status
```

[Source](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1410536-391-1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

SQL stores the history and statuses of SQL jobs in sysjobshistory.SQL can alert you through email,write to event log.But as per my understanding,there is no event which you can subscribe to see the status..

There are some examples in C# which does the same way of repeatedly polling to see the job [status](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/367470/Manage-SQL-Server-Agent-Jobs-using-Csharp)  which is same as you running a query to check the job.

Almost all the methods that are available requires you to poll and see the status,but doesnt give you an option to subscribe to job completed event